# Disk clean on startup freezes and doesn't continue to start up

Tags: startup, disk

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop
GPU: Nvidia 3060

Recently I set my wallpaper and after pressing replace the OS crashed and would no longer boot. It now freezes on the screen in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried `fsck` and also updating the system, reinstalling my graphics drivers and updating the system, but it's still not booting to the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by booting into safe mode purging nvidia 515 drivers than installing nvidia 470 drivers